# Why is data returned from an ASP.NET page method inside a .d property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In a jQuery Ajax call to an ASP.NET page method like so:

```
function getUsers() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://{localhost}:8078/Default.aspx/GetJson2",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          success:  function (msg) {
              $("#Result").text(msg.d)
          }
      )};
```

the data returned from the server is inside a property `.d` of the `msg` even though my CLR object has no such property. Why is this?

Comment: I'll just leave it here: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what OP said in comments about the intent of the question, but that makes it a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263916/why-does-web-service-return-data-as-msg-d

Answer (score 2):

It's placing the value of `msg.d` as text into the element with an id of `Result`

Comment: what is d doing in msg.d.

Comment: @KarthikDheeraj `msg` is an object, and `d` is a property of `msg`.

Answer (score 1):

getUsers is sending an ajax request to http://{localhost}:8078/Default.aspx/GetJson2 and receiving a json string which JQuery is automatically parsing into a javascript object (msg). Then the 'd' property of this object is inserted as text into the DOM element with an id of "Result"